# Build complete on maven/Tomcat, but page data cut off (not css)

Tags: html, maven, tomcat

I have a really strange issue where an identical build has data "cut off" where the page or server has just decided to stop loading the rest of the site. This happens for every page on the site.

I've done comparisons between other people's projects, redownloaded everything, and still nothing seems to work, so I'm looking for complete shots in the dark, has anyone seen anything like this before?

[image]

You can see the tag is cut off mid-point. This happens at roughly the same spot, so if more lines are added, it would still be around "line 592" data wise. It's like if there were 10,000 characters, it always cuts off at 1,000.

I've put in hours on this and have gotten nowhere, I'm looking for pretty much anything.

The build process is maven, with a grunt build inside of it, and Tomcat server.

There is ONE exception to this, and that is if I serve it with a livereload grunt-npm server it runs fine and loads the whole thing without a problem. That isn't the deployment environment unfortunately.

This version (an older one) also runs fine on other people's systems, but the trunk is hosed for them too.

Comment: What Tomcat and Java version do you use? Perhaps you could even share its server.xml config file.

Comment: 8 for both, server setup is identical for deployment and other projects work on it

Comment: Well, hard to say without knowing more about your code and configuration. E.g. are there any filters in place? Is this Tomcat running on your machine (server), or in any cloud environment (e.g. Openshift)?

Comment: In your code that sends the response, do you use `response.setContentLength()`?  If so, possibly the length is set to the wrong value or the response contents are changed after the length is set.